# MSBUILD error CA0053 : Unable to load rule assembly

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2010

When running MSBUILD as part of an automated build process I get:

> MSBUILD : error : CA0053 : Unable to load rule assembly 'c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\team tools\static analysis
>   tools\fxcop\rules\securityrules.dll': Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\team
>   tools\static analysis tools\fxcop\rules\securityrules.dll' or one of
>   its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly
>   manifest.

The project contains several rulesets.

Even from inside Visual Studio 2010 SP I get the same message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run the Visual Studio 2010 setup and repaired installation. Followed the same approach with Service Pack 1 and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

An possible reason could be the fact that in some cases the full path of the tools is stored in the projects file. 
I had the problem with VS 2012. See [MS Connect Error](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/732031/error-ca0053-due-to-failure-to-load-rules-dll-when-running-code-analysis)

Answer (score 1):

An possible solution to this problem is to unblock the files (right click -> properties -> unblock) when they are downloaded from a different computer.